# How to fetch data of a particular id refrenced by foreign key django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

There a list of all the questions with correct and incorrect (scores if question is wrong and right) with Add button attached to each.

When I click add button the question are added to quiz into `QuestionQuiz` ,model along with their scores correct get +1 and incorrect -1 are updated to the database.

The corresponding quiz id is send thru the url in the form view image attached below: `path('filter_list/<pk>',views.FilterQuestionView.as_view(),name='filter'),`

> What I want to achieve here is when page loads initially I want to
>   show the scores for the corresponding question based on the quiz id  fetched 
>   from database. How can I get all question title and description and if question added to quiz or not
>
> What would be django way to achieve this ?

May be there's a to get all data including the ones already added in quiz like its currently fetching
`title,description`  rest fields are static

I could change fetch `title,decription,correct,incorrect,flag(true if added to current quiz_id else false)`

Image is attached

[image: Here]

Suppose a question is added to quiz. The text in the button must be ***ADDED*** and the correct and incorrect must be updated when the page is loaded initially. Here first question is added to the quiz. 
NOTE: Value = 1 is default values which is updated by user for correct and incorrect.

Following is model I have created:

```js
class Question(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=255 )
 description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
  

class Quiz(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=225,blank=False )
 quiz_type =models.IntegerField(choices=QUIZ_TYPE,default=0)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField( Question, through='QuestionQuiz', related_name="quiz_question") 
 categories= models.ManyToManyField(Category,through='CategoryQuiz',related_name='quiz_category')  
 

class QuestionQuiz(models.Model):
 quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
 correct =models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
    incorrect= models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3) 

 class Meta:
  unique_together = ('quiz','question')
```

Views.py - Used django_filter package to create filter

```js
class FilterQuestionView( AddQuestionAjaxFormMixin,FormMixin,FilterView):
 
 form_class = QuestionQuizForm
 filterset_class =  QuestionFilter
 paginate_by = 5
 context_object_name = 'questions'
```

This is  template :

```js
{% for question in questions %}
     <tr>
        <form method='POST'   id="q_{{question.id}}"> 
     <td>{{question.title}}</td>
     <td>{{question.description}}</td>
     

      
      <td><input type="text" value="1" id="correct_{{question.id}}"></td>

      <td><input type="text" value="1" id="incorrect_{{question.id}}"></td>
      <td> 
            <a id="btn_{{question.id}}" class="btn purple-gradient" onclick="addRemoveQuestion({{question.id}},{{quiz}})"  >Add</a>
       </td>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using django_filter here. You can override its qs function in the QuestionFilter. This may help you extend your query in your way. The returned result could contain a flag suggesting its already added to quiz or not. Link reference contains the qs function extend detail.  [qs function](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs)

`def qs(self):
        parent = super().qs
        d= parent.prefetch_related('quizquestion')
        return d`

Comment: Let me try if this achieves target

Answer (score 2):

You can use prefetch in order get data from related table in an inverse relationship

`q = Question.objects.prefetch_related( 'questionquiz_set')`

All question with quiz will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your question a little bit to be more understandable because it's not clear yet for me. I am sorry I am not able to add comment due to the reputation.
However, I don't know if you that answer or not but you can use

```py
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super(FilterQuestionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

then you can add whatever you query from the database in the context dictionary by creating the query that suits your case.

Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) to see how to create a good query.

I hope this could help.

Comment: I have updated the question with other details now.

Comment: I just read it again. So far what I understood  is that you don't want to show all the questions in database you want the questions related to the quiz. is that right ?

Comment: No I want to show all the question but if a question is in the quiz then that question must be marked as ADDED instead of ADD on button text

Comment: you can return a dictionary of the questions that are already inside the quiz. then a simple if condition before ```<a id="btn_{{question.id}}" class="btn purple-gradient" onclick="addRemoveQuestion({{question.id}},{{quiz}})"  >Add</a> ``` to check if the question is inside this dictionary or not. if true put ADDED else you put Add. Tell me if this works